# Описание сайта в поисковиках

Tags: поисковые-системы, индексация

По какому принципу поисковые боты берут описание сайта со страницы?
У меня такое чувство что это полностью не предсказуемая штука.

В моем случае сначала он подхватывал самый первый, по иерархии html, текст который был вообще скрыт, я перенес весь скрытый текст вниз страницы, после этого поисковой бот сделал не поддающееся логике, взял одно предложение из текста по середине страницы, и одно предложение из скрытого текста который находится в низу страницы.

Может я что-то не понимаю и есть какие то специальные теги для поисковиков?

Comment: Между тегами `<head></head>` html-страницы нужно вставить: `<meta name="description" content="Описание">`, вместо `Описание` вставить то, что Вы хотите увидеть в сниппете. Но иногда всё равно показывается непонятно что. В таком случае лично мне помогало соблюдение рекомендаций [**валидатора**](https://validator.w3.org/) — при последующем индексировании страницы выводилось требуемое мне описание.

Comment: Если воспринимать вопрос буквально. Когда Вы вводите в форму поисковика текст, содержащийся на странице Вашего сайта, в сниппете показывается кусок с этим текстом. Если же вводите заголовок или ключевые слова страницы (что Вы, скорее всего, и проделывали, а может, вбивали адрес сайта), то да, мне тоже представляется, что логику краулеров понять трудно: так, однажды на моём сайте Google показывал в выдаче кнопки виджета социальных сетей. Чтобы управлять содержанием сниппетов в этом случае, см. комментарий выше.

Comment: Не знаю про LinkedIn, но "промышленно принятое решение" для таких вещей -- [OpenGraph Protocol](http://ogp.me/).

Comment: Пожалуйста, разделите вопрос на два атомарных (самостоятельных) .

Comment: @NickVolynkin, автор в последний раз заходил 22 февраля, уже может и не появиться, да и, вероятно, лично для него вопрос потерял актуальность. Могут ли сторонние участники делить вопрос на самостоятельные?

Comment: @СашаЧерных тогда сделаем проще.